# Error: "The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the gapi.client library is not loaded in your page" -- FLUTTER WEB

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

I'm encountering an issue in my web application when trying to make API calls using the Google API client library. The error message I'm seeing is:

> The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the gapi.client
> library is not loaded in your page.

Additionally, the function seems to be returning null and does not produce any UserCredential. Here's a snippet of the Dart code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

static Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle(
    void2BoolFunc setLoading, void2StringFunc setErrorMessage) async {
  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    if (googleUser == null) {
      setLoading(false);
      setErrorMessage("Google sign-in was canceled by the user.");
      return null;
    }

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    // Get AuthCredential from GoogleSignInAuthentication
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    ) as AuthCredential; // Cast to AuthCredential

    debugPrint("Credentials --> ${credential.toString()}\n");

    // Use AuthCredential to sign in with Firebase
    UserCredential userCred = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    debugPrint("USER CRED --> ${userCred.toString()}");

    return userCred;
  } catch (e) {
    setLoading(false);
    setErrorMessage("Fetching user details failed! Error: ${e.toString()}");
    debugPrint("Exception --> ${e.toString()}");
    return null;
  }
}
```

I've checked the OAuth configuration, included the necessary libraries, and followed the asynchronous loading patterns. Despite this, the function returns null without producing any UserCredential. Any insights on resolving both the error and the null return would be appreciated.